# CSS3 animation-delay start

Tags: css-animations

**Hi I have an animation which starts at different time
First I have a
brand image with animation zoom is ok second I have two border top /
bottom ) animation is ok too but the third is that the right and left side of this second animation must start after border top and bottom
animation stop. the delay doesn't work

On CodePen it's working a few because I see a weird
thing before the right border animation. Someone has an idea ?**

```
My code here
```

http://codepen.io/heysabbinah/pen/VjpVza?editors=1100

Comment: The animation-delay doesn't work even if she works on codepen

Answer (score 1):

```
I think because you did not calculate width for margins, I have updated your code

[http://codepen.io/manthan11/pen/bZWwqQ?editors=1100][1]

Hope this is what you want.
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same fix. The margins we're off - good spot. The animation looks clear now :)

Comment: yes it's good thanks a lot !  have another problem i want the same in left but from bottom to top . did i have to take the same code or i must have another one with y ? thanks again

Comment: the delay don't work it work on codepen only i don't know why